# compression algorithm for bitmap images

Tags: image, compression

Are there algorithms for lossless compression of bitmap images that beat the LZ family? Suitable for an embedded environment.

Requirements:

- maximum compression
- geared towards images with low bpp: 2-8, max 15
- low memory consumption or in-place decompression
- fast decompression

Comment: How do the usual suspects (gzip, bzip2, lzma, PNG) perform on the corpus of images you need to compress? Do they decompress in realtime on your target platform? Can you tell me more about the characteristics of your image corpus? Photo-realistic (though low bpp) or computer generated? Paletted colors?

Comment: @Mike: All your questions have already been answered. Yes, images are palette based, therefore a specialized compression would probably yield better results than general purpose LZ. Algorithms like LZMA/PPMD are impractical. Realtime decompression would be ideal but not a requirement.

Comment: While 2-8 bpp usually implies a palette, 15 bpp makes me think RGB555. Is your 15 bpp case really a palette? Also, bzip2 is not part of the LZ family, so I wanted to ask about that too (but that's compression pedantry). Based on your description so far, I'm inferring a fair amount of visual diversity in your corpus's characteristics, which may make it difficult to find a single format that compresses all of them better than, say PNG.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution? Could you share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

One candidate might be Rad Game Tools' Smacker algorithm. Their free compression tools can be downloaded at http://www.radgametools.com/smkdown.htm

Advantages: Smacker video has been in use since the mid-1990's and can decode in real-time on i486 computers with meager amounts of RAM (by today's standards). Although it's a video format, many games have used it for still images.

Disadvantages: While it's paletted, I'm not entirely sure it's lossless. It probably has dials for that, though. Also, if you're planning to distribute a product based on it, you are expected to pay for a license. I have no idea what kind of platform you need this for, but they might not have a decoder ready for you. Fortunately, there's an open source decoder in the FFmpeg project but again, licensing issues-- don't know if they would sign off on you using the open source decoder even if you bought a license.

If this doesn't fit your needs, you'll have to supply more details with more concrete goals, starting with a bake-off demonstrating how the common compression formats operate on your corpus and what specific targets (compression and speed-wise) you would like to achieve.